# How to get last two numbers from year in a variable expression for ssis package?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, dataflowtask

I am dynamically generating the date for ssis tranformation using variable expression.
My below expression generates the output like:

```
02102014.csv
Expression :
+RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)  MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2)
+(DT_WSTR, 4)  YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate()))+ ".csv"
```

How can I get the value like `021014.csv`. In the year string it should pick up only last two values. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2)
+ RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2)+ ".csv"
```

Result:

```
021014.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)  MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -3, getdate())), 2)
+RIGHT("1"+(DT_WSTR, 4)  YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())),2)+ ".csv"
```